# xsl form validation with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I am stuck in a piece of code. I am not able to validate a form when I am using xsl. But the same works with html.

Its really weird and I do not know the solution.

**My HTML CODE WHICH WORKS PERFECT.**

```
<body>
<form name="myform" method="post" action="http://www.google.com" onsubmit="return validateform()" >
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
</body>
```

**My XSL Code which does not validate and directly reaches the URL.**

```
<xsl:element name="form">
                  <xsl:attribute name="name">myform</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="method">post</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="action">http://www.google.com</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="onsubmit">return validateform();</xsl:attribute>

                  <xsl:element name="input">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">name</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:element>

                  <xsl:element name="input">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">password</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">password</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:element>

                  <xsl:element name="input">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">submit</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">register</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:element>

           </xsl:element>
```

**MY JS which is same for both**

```
<script>
function validateform(){
 var name=document.myform.name.value;
 var password=document.myform.password.value;
 if (name==null || name==""){
  alert("Name can't be blank");  
  return false;  
 }
 else if(password.length<6){  
 alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");  
 return false;  
 }  
}
</script>
```

It gives an error in my console after clicking register that " Cannot read property "value" of undefined.

P.S: I do not want to use required attribute because it does not work on IE and I do not want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but you left out some information.
Is the script part also generated via xslt? How is the xslt processor called? In browser?

But one hint may be, if the script part is generated via xslt and as posted part of your xslt file. This in not valid XML (XSLT). 
You need to escape some character (&,<).
In your case change:

```
else if(password.length<6){
```

to

```
 else if(password.length &lt; 6){
```

Update:

If there are more then one form with the same name. Change your validateform function form

```
 function validateform(){
   var name=document.myform.name.value;
   //...
 }
```

To (use form as parameter):

```
function validateform(form){
  var name= form.elements['name'].value;
  //...
}
```

And use it:  `onsubmit="return validateform(this)"`

Comment: The script is not generated via xslt. the script is in a seperate JS file and it is included in my classic asp. Also the XSL processor is called in my asp.

Comment: Yes the above does not fit to the log messages.  Another guess, the generated html has a different document declaration and the not standard element access does `document.myform.name` does not work.  Try `document.myform.elements['name']`. Or  there is a second form myform in your generated html.  Also it would be better to call `validateform(this)` and then use thisform.elements['name'].

Comment: Thanks for this. You are right. The element is getting copied and whatever element i create there is a duplicate of it. But i need the duplicate copy as well.

    document.myform[1].name.value worked for me.

Just i need help in my JS now. Can you please post the code with the function validateform(this){}

Comment: i cannot use document.myform[1] all time because it form array may increase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I am new to java script so deep diving into the new project on which i am working.:)